# math.net DenseVectors vs DenseMatrix 1xn | nx1

Tags: f#, matrix-multiplication, math.net, mathnet-numerics

This is really simple stuff but, as I am a noob with math.net, I may need to be pointed in the right direction:

```
let a = new DenseVector([| 5.0; 2.0; 3.0; |])
let m = new DenseMatrix(3, 3, 1.0)
let r = a * m 
let r2 = m * a
```

results in:

```
> r;;
val it : DenseVector = seq [10.0; 10.0; 10.0]
> r2;;
val it : DenseVector = seq [10.0; 10.0; 10.0]
```

Matrix-Vector multiplication takes too much liberty here. I need to enforce proper dimensionality checks. Should I just work with `DenseMatrix`, creating 1xn, nx1 matrices?
This basically makes `Vectors` and `DenseVectors` redundant in my case.

Comment: I disagree: the solution to some of the issues above could eventually be bundled in a unique implementation; and a broader picture on what I am trying to achieve may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observed behavior of Matrix-Vector and Vector-Matrix multiplication in the library is by design. Distinguishing `column` and `row` vectors is not possible within mere `Vector` type, so explicit matrix-by-vector multiply and vector-by-matrix multiply operations simply have respective signatures:

```
Matrix.Multiply: Vector -> Vector // matrix-by-vector
```

and

```
Matrix.LeftMultiply: Vector -> Vector // vector-by-matrix
```

where in the first case both argument and result are assumed `column` vectors, and in the second case both are assumed `row` ones.

The library always assumes "right" vector orientation when chaining operations in more complex expressions, at the same time enforcing other dimensionality checks, indeed.

If you want for whatever reason to explicitly distinguishing `row` from `column` vectors and carry, if required, the burden of explicit transpositions, then using `1-by-n` and `n-by-1` matrices in place of `row` and `column` vectors respectively is the way to go. In this case if matrix dimensions do not agree the library will be throwing `System.ArgumentException` instead of silently assuming "right" transposition.